# Pairwise Mahalanobis Distance Between Multiple Independent Variables and a Dependent Variable With Three Classes in R

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis, mahalanobis, pairwise-distance

**Issue**

I'm having some trouble calculating the Mahalanobis Distance between three classes of the independent variable `Country`.

My aim is to calculate the `Mahalanobis distance` among dolphin whistle acoustic parameters measured from a spectrogram taken from `three populations` in `three different study regions`. I want to calculate potential `(dis)similarity` amongst whistle types.

- My dependent variable has three classes `"France", "Spain" and "Italy"`
- My data frame has are multiple variables (features of
  whistle type aspects) to be taken into account.
- There are multiple observations per group (obs = 367; indicating the data frame contains more than one row per Country).

**Dataframe structure**

```
'data.frame':   367 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Country    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Holland","France",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Low.Freq   : num  -0.245 -1.846 -1.369 -2.022 2.045 ...
 $ High.Freq  : num  -0.684 -2.033 -2.128 -2.643 0.358 ...
 $ Peak.Freq  : num  -0.0879 -1.3636 -0.8557 -1.4291 0.2001 ...
 $ Delta.Freq : num  -0.384 -0.588 -0.922 -0.973 -0.664 ...
 $ Delta.Time : num  -1.48 -1.124 -0.861 -0.999 -1.696 ...
 $ Peak.Time  : num  0.0383 0.3698 0.3703 -0.7444 -0.3214 ...
 $ Center.Freq: num  -0.169 -1.157 -1.032 -1.556 0.16 ...
 $ Start.Freq : num  -0.741 -0.944 -1.149 -1.712 0.905 ...
 $ End.Freq   : num  -0.335 -1.495 -1.561 -2.242 0.704 ...
```

I found a StackOverflow question that covered exactly what I want to achieve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608280/mahalanobis-distance-with-multiple-observations-per-group) but the problem is they conduct a `pairwise mahalanobis distance analysis` using the function `pairwise.mahalanobis()` from the `HDMD package`. However, when I try and download the package, I get this message.

**Warning Message**

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘HDMD’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

#Ive tried these different methods to find the package but nothing works

ap <- available.packages()
View(ap)
"HDMD" %in% rownames(ap)

install.packages("HDMD", dependencies = TRUE)

av <- available.packages(filters=list())
av[av[, "Package"] == HDMD, ]

install.packages('HDMD',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

I can't seem to find another function that behaves in the same way as the function `pairwise.mahalanobis()` except for a loop on this StackOverflow question,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181618/calculating-weigthed-pairwise-mahalanobis-distanceshttps://), which I also could not get to work.

Does anyone know how to achieve the type of analysis I'm attempting because I can't figure out how?

If anyone can lend a hand, I would be very grateful.

**R-CODE**

```
    library(HDMD) #pairwise.mahalanobis function
    library(cluster) #agnes function
    library(biotools)

    group = matrix(Cluster_Dummy_2$Country) #what is being compared
    group = t(group[,1]) #prepare for pairwise.mahalanobis function
    
    variables = c(variables = c("Low.Freq", "High.Freq", "Peak.Freq", "Delta.Freq", "Delta.Time", "Peak.Time", 
                                "Center.Freq", "Start.Freq","End.Freq")) #variables (what is being used for comparison)
    variables = as.matrix(Cluster_Dummy_2[,variables]) #prepare for pairwise.mahalanobis function
```

**The original code has the function pairwise.mahalanobis() in the HDMD package:**

```
mahala_sq = pairwise.mahalanobis(x=variables, grouping=group) #get squared mahalanobis distances (see mahala_sq$distance).
```

**I decided to try D2.dist() using the biotools package**

```
mahala_sq = D2.dist(variables, group) #get squared mahalanobis distances (see mahala_sq$distance).
names = rownames(mahala_sq$means) #capture labels

#Error 
Error in D2.dist(variables, group, inverted = FALSE) : 
  incompatible dimensions!
```

**Rest of the code to produce a dendrogram**

```
mahala = sqrt(mahala_sq$distance) #mahalanobis distance
rownames(mahala) = names #set rownames in the dissimilarity matrix
colnames(mahala) = names #set colnames in the dissimilarity matrix

#This is how I used the dissimilarity matrix to find clusters.
cluster = agnes(mahala,diss=TRUE,keep.diss=FALSE,method="complete") #hierarchical clustering
plot(cluster,which.plots=2) #plot dendrogram
```

Data frame

```
structure(list(Low.Freq = c(435L, 94103292L, 1L, 2688L, 8471L, 
    28818L, 654755585L, 468628164L, 342491L, 2288474L, 3915L, 411L, 
    267864894L, 3312618L, 5383L, 8989443L, 1894L, 534981L, 9544861L, 
    3437614L, 475386L, 7550764L, 48744L, 2317845L, 5126197L, 2445L, 
    8L, 557450L, 450259742L, 21006647L, 9L, 7234027L, 59L, 9L, 605L, 
    9199L, 3022L, 30218156L, 46423L, 38L, 88L, 396396244L, 28934316L, 
    7723L, 95688045L, 679354L, 716352L, 76289L, 332826763L, 6L, 90975L, 
    83103577L, 9529L, 229093L, 42810L, 5L, 18175302L, 1443751L, 5831L, 
    8303661L, 86L, 778L, 23947L, 8L, 9829740L, 2075838L, 7434328L, 
    82174987L, 2L, 94037071L, 9638653L, 5L, 3L, 65972L, 0L, 936779338L, 
    4885076L, 745L, 8L, 56456L, 125140L, 73043989L, 516476L, 7L, 
    4440739L, 612L, 3966L, 8L, 9255L, 84127L, 96218L, 5690L, 56L, 
    3561L, 78738L, 1803363L, 809369L, 7131L, 0L), High.Freq = c(6071L, 
    3210L, 6L, 7306092L, 6919054L, 666399L, 78L, 523880161L, 4700783L, 
    4173830L, 30L, 811L, 341014L, 780L, 44749L, 91L, 201620707L, 
    74L, 1L, 65422L, 595L, 89093186L, 946520L, 6940919L, 655350L, 
    4L, 6L, 618L, 2006697L, 889L, 1398L, 28769L, 90519642L, 984L, 
    0L, 296209525L, 487088392L, 5L, 894L, 529L, 5L, 99106L, 2L, 926017L, 
    9078L, 1L, 21L, 88601017L, 575770L, 48L, 8431L, 194L, 62324996L, 
    5L, 81L, 40634727L, 806901520L, 6818173L, 3501L, 91780L, 36106039L, 
    5834347L, 58388837L, 34L, 3280L, 6507606L, 19L, 402L, 584L, 76L, 
    4078684L, 199L, 6881L, 92251L, 81715L, 40L, 327L, 57764L, 97668898L, 
    2676483L, 76L, 4694L, 817120L, 51L, 116712L, 666L, 3L, 42841L, 
    9724L, 21L, 4L, 359L, 2604L, 22L, 30490L, 5640L, 34L, 51923625L, 
    35544L), Peak.Freq = c(87005561L, 9102L, 994839015L, 42745869L, 
    32840L, 62737133L, 2722L, 24L, 67404881L, 999242982L, 3048L, 
    85315406L, 703037627L, 331264L, 8403609L, 3934064L, 50578953L, 
    370110665L, 3414L, 12657L, 40L, 432L, 7707L, 214L, 68588962L, 
    69467L, 75L, 500297L, 704L, 1L, 102659072L, 60896923L, 4481230L, 
    94124925L, 60164619L, 447L, 580L, 8L, 172L, 9478521L, 20L, 53L, 
    3072127L, 2160L, 27301893L, 8L, 4263L, 508L, 712409L, 50677L, 
    522433683L, 112844L, 193385L, 458269L, 93578705L, 22093131L, 
    6L, 9L, 1690461L, 0L, 4L, 652847L, 44767L, 21408L, 5384L, 304L, 
    721L, 651147L, 2426L, 586L, 498289375L, 945L, 6L, 816L, 46207L, 
    39135L, 6621028L, 66905L, 26905085L, 4098L, 0L, 14L, 88L, 530L, 
    97809006L, 90L, 6L, 260792844L, 9L, 833205723L, 99467321L, 5L, 
    8455640L, 54090L, 2L, 309L, 299161148L, 4952L, 454824L), Delta.Freq = c(5L, 
    78L, 88553L, 794L, 5L, 3859122L, 782L, 36L, 8756801L, 243169338L, 
    817789L, 8792384L, 7431L, 626921743L, 9206L, 95789L, 7916L, 8143453L, 
    6L, 4L, 6363L, 181125L, 259618L, 6751L, 33L, 37960L, 0L, 2L, 
    599582228L, 565585L, 19L, 48L, 269450424L, 70676581L, 7830566L, 
    4L, 86484313L, 21L, 90899794L, 2L, 72356L, 574280L, 869544L, 
    73418L, 6468164L, 2259L, 5938505L, 31329L, 1249L, 354L, 8817L, 
    3L, 2568L, 82809L, 29836269L, 5230L, 37L, 33752014L, 79307L, 
    1736L, 8522076L, 40L, 2289135L, 862L, 801448L, 8026L, 5L, 15L, 
    4393771L, 405914L, 71098L, 950288L, 8319L, 1396973L, 832L, 70L, 
    1746L, 61907L, 8709547L, 300750537L, 45862L, 91417085L, 79892L, 
    47765L, 5477L, 18L, 4186L, 2860L, 754038591L, 375L, 53809223L, 
    72L, 136L, 509L, 232325L, 13128104L, 1692L, 8581L, 23L), Delta.Time = c(1361082L, 
    7926L, 499L, 5004L, 3494530L, 213L, 64551179L, 70L, 797L, 5L, 
    72588L, 86976L, 5163L, 635080L, 3L, 91L, 919806257L, 81443L, 
    3135427L, 4410972L, 5810L, 8L, 46603718L, 422L, 1083626L, 48L, 
    15699890L, 7L, 90167635L, 446459879L, 2332071L, 761660L, 49218442L, 
    381L, 46L, 493197L, 46L, 798597155L, 45342274L, 6265842L, 6L, 
    3445819L, 351L, 1761227L, 214L, 959L, 908996387L, 6L, 3855L, 
    9096604L, 152664L, 7970052L, 32366926L, 31L, 5201618L, 114L, 
    7806411L, 70L, 239L, 5065L, 2L, 1L, 14472831L, 122042249L, 8L, 
    495604L, 29L, 8965478L, 2875L, 959L, 39L, 9L, 690L, 933626665L, 
    85294L, 580093L, 95934L, 982058L, 65244056L, 137508L, 29L, 7621L, 
    7527L, 72L, 2L, 315L, 6L, 2413L, 8625150L, 51298109L, 851L, 890460L, 
    160736L, 6L, 850842734L, 2L, 7L, 76969113L, 190536L), Peak.Time = c(1465265L, 
    452894L, 545076172L, 8226275L, 5040875L, 700530L, 1L, 3639L, 
    20141L, 71712131L, 686L, 923L, 770569738L, 69961L, 737458636L, 
    122403L, 199502046L, 6108L, 907L, 108078263L, 7817L, 4L, 6L, 
    69L, 721L, 786353L, 87486L, 1563L, 876L, 47599535L, 79295722L, 
    53L, 7378L, 591L, 6607935L, 954L, 6295L, 75514344L, 5742050L, 
    25647276L, 449L, 328566184L, 4L, 2L, 2703L, 21367543L, 63429043L, 
    708L, 782L, 909820L, 478L, 50L, 922L, 579882L, 7850L, 534L, 2157492L, 
    96L, 6L, 716L, 5L, 653290336L, 447854237L, 2L, 31972263L, 645L, 
    7L, 609909L, 4054695L, 455631L, 4919894L, 9L, 72713L, 9997L, 
    84090765L, 89742L, 5L, 5028L, 4126L, 23091L, 81L, 239635020L, 
    3576L, 898597785L, 6822L, 3798L, 201999L, 19624L, 20432923L, 
    18944093L, 930720236L, 1492302L, 300122L, 143633L, 5152743L, 
    417344L, 813L, 55792L, 78L), Center_Freq = c(61907L, 8709547L, 
    300750537L, 45862L, 91417085L, 79892L, 47765L, 5477L, 18L, 4186L, 
    2860L, 754038591L, 375L, 53809223L, 72L, 136L, 4700783L, 4173830L, 
    30L, 811L, 341014L, 780L, 44749L, 91L, 201620707L, 74L, 1L, 65422L, 
    595L, 89093186L, 946520L, 6940919L, 48744L, 2317845L, 5126197L, 
    2445L, 8L, 557450L, 450259742L, 21006647L, 9L, 7234027L, 59L, 
    9L, 651547554L, 45554L, 38493L, 91055218L, 38L, 1116474L, 2295482L, 
    3001L, 9L, 3270L, 141L, 53644L, 667983L, 565598L, 84L, 971L, 
    555498297L, 60431L, 6597L, 856943893L, 607815536L, 4406L, 79L, 
    4885076L, 745L, 8L, 56456L, 125140L, 73043989L, 516476L, 7L, 
    4440739L, 754038591L, 375L, 53809223L, 72L, 136L, 509L, 232325L, 
    13128104L, 1692L, 8581L, 23L, 5874213L, 4550L, 644668065L, 3712371L, 
    5928L, 8833L, 7L, 2186023L, 61627221L, 37297L, 716427989L, 21387L
    ), Start.Freq = c(426355L, 22073538L, 680374L, 41771L, 54L, 6762844L, 
    599171L, 108L, 257451851L, 438814L, 343045L, 4702L, 967787L, 
    1937L, 18L, 89301735L, 366L, 90L, 954L, 7337732L, 70891703L, 
    4139L, 10397931L, 940000382L, 7L, 38376L, 878528819L, 6287L, 
    738366L, 31L, 47L, 5L, 6L, 77848L, 2366508L, 45L, 3665842L, 7252260L, 
    6L, 61L, 3247L, 448348L, 1L, 705132L, 144L, 7423637L, 2L, 497L, 
    844927639L, 78978L, 914L, 131L, 7089563L, 927L, 9595581L, 2774463L, 
    1651L, 73509280L, 7L, 35L, 18L, 96L, 1L, 92545512L, 27354947L, 
    7556L, 65019L, 7480L, 71835L, 8249L, 64792L, 71537L, 349389666L, 
    280244484L, 82L, 6L, 40L, 353872L, 0L, 103L, 1255L, 4752L, 29L, 
    76L, 81185L, 14L, 9L, 470775630L, 818361265L, 57947209L, 44L, 
    24L, 41295L, 4L, 261449L, 9931404L, 773556640L, 930717L, 65007421L
    ), End.Freq = c(71000996L, 11613579L, 71377155L, 1942738L, 8760748L, 
    79L, 455L, 374L, 8L, 5L, 2266932L, 597833L, 155488L, 3020L, 4L, 
    554L, 4L, 16472L, 1945649L, 668181101L, 649780L, 22394365L, 93060602L, 
    172146L, 20472L, 23558847L, 190513L, 22759044L, 44L, 78450L, 
    205621181L, 218L, 69916344L, 23884L, 66L, 312148L, 7710564L, 
    4L, 422L, 744572L, 651547554L, 45554L, 38493L, 91055218L, 38L, 
    1116474L, 2295482L, 3001L, 9L, 3270L, 141L, 55595L, 38451L, 8660867L, 
    14L, 96L, 345L, 6L, 44L, 8235824L, 910517L, 1424326L, 87102566L, 
    53644L, 667983L, 565598L, 84L, 971L, 555498297L, 60431L, 6597L, 
    856943893L, 607815536L, 4406L, 79L, 7L, 28978746L, 7537295L, 
    6L, 633L, 345860066L, 802L, 1035131L, 602L, 2740L, 8065L, 61370968L, 
    429953765L, 981507L, 8105L, 343787257L, 44782L, 64184L, 12981359L, 
    123367978L, 818775L, 123745614L, 25345654L, 3L), Country = c("Holland", 
    "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
    "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Holland", 
    "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
    "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "France", "France", "France")), row.names = c(NA, 
    99L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code to download the function pairwise.mahalanobis() from the HDMD package**

```
#install.packages("biotools")
#install.packages("cluster")

library(biotools) #pairwise.mahalanobis function
library(cluster) #agnes function

group = matrix(Cluster_Dummy_2$Country) #what is being compared
group = t(group[,1]) #prepare for pairwise.mahalanobis function

variables = c(variables = c("Low.Freq", "High.Freq", "Peak.Freq", "Delta.Freq", "Delta.Time", "Peak.Time", 
                            "Center.Freq", "Start.Freq","End.Freq")) #variables (what is being used for comparison)

variables = as.matrix(Cluster_Dummy_2[,variables]) #prepare for pairwise.mahalanobis function
variables

#function for calculating the Mahalanobis distance

#REF:https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/HDMD/

#HDMD Package download

pairwise.mahalanobis = 
  function(x, grouping=NULL, cov =NULL, inverted=FALSE, digits = 5, ...) 
  {
    x <- if (is.vector(x))                                  #standardize input data as matrix
      matrix(x, ncol = length(x))
    else as.matrix(x)
    
    if(!is.matrix(x))
      stop("x could not be forced into a matrix")
    
    if(length(grouping) ==0){                               #no group assigned, uses first col
      grouping = t(x[1])
      x = x[2:dim(x)[2]]    
      cat("assigning grouping\n")
      print(grouping)
    }
    
    n <- nrow(x)
    p <- ncol(x)
    
    if (n != length(grouping)){                                 #grouping and matrix do not correspond
      cat(paste("n: ", n, "and groups: ", length(grouping), "\n"))
      stop("nrow(x) and length(grouping) are different")
    }
    g <- as.factor(grouping)
    g
    lev <- lev1 <- levels(g)                                # Groups
    counts <- as.vector(table(g))                           # No. of elements in each group
    
    if (any(counts == 0)) {                             # Remove grouping if not represented in data
      empty <- lev[counts == 0]
      warning(sprintf(ngettext(length(empty), "group %s is empty", 
                               "groups %s are empty"), paste(empty, collapse = " ")), 
              domain = NA)
      lev1 <- lev[counts > 0]
      g <- factor(g, levels = lev1)
      counts <- as.vector(table(g))
    }
    
    ng = length(lev1)
    
    group.means <- tapply(x, list(rep(g, p), col(x)), mean)     # g x p matrix of group means from x
    
    if(missing(cov)){                                           #create covariance matrix
      inverted = FALSE
      cov = cor(x)                                          #standardize into correlation mtx
    }
    else{                                                       #check cov of correct dimension
      if(dim(cov) != c(p,p))
        stop("cov matrix not of dim = (p,p)\n")
    }
    
    Distance = matrix(nrow=ng, ncol=ng)                                 #initialize distance matrix 
    dimnames(Distance) = list(names(group.means), names(group.means))
    
    Means = round(group.means, digits)
    Cov = round(cov, digits)
    Distance = round(Distance, digits)
    
    for(i in 1:ng){
      Distance[i,]= mahalanobis(group.means, group.means[i,], cov, inverted)
    }
    
    result <- list(means = group.means, cov = cov, distance = Distance)
    result
  }

Calculate the pairwise Mahalanobis distance

#Calculate the Mahalanobis distance
mahala_sq = pairwise.mahalanobis(x=variables, grouping=group) #get squared mahalanobis distances (see mahala_sq$distance).
mahala_sq

names = rownames(mahala_sq$means) #capture labels

mahala = sqrt(mahala_sq$distance) #mahalanobis distance
rownames(mahala) = names #set rownames in the dissimilarity matrix
colnames(mahala) = names #set colnames in the dissimilarity matrix

mahala 

#This is how I used the dissimilarity matrix to find clusters.
cluster = agnes(mahala,diss=TRUE,keep.diss=FALSE,method="complete") #hierarchical clustering
plot(cluster,which.plots=2) #plot dendrogram
```